# Get the last substring separated with /

Tags: javascript

Currently with my code:

```
window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]
```

I can get "comparative" from:

```
http://localhost/study/78/comparative
```

But it's possible that some subdirectories will be added to the URI.

How can I get the last substring (the most to the right) on the URI separated with `/` ?

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Comment: `x.substr(x.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);` is one way

Comment: I like Alex's better, less instructions. Though I personally prefer `String.prototype.slice()` over `String.prototype.substr()`.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0];` is one way

Comment: Another one(but a bit less efficient) `window.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]`

or

`window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

or

`window.location.pathname.substr(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

Comment: what's the point of `.slice(-1)` if you're going to call `.pop()`?

Comment: The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object. And The pop() method removes the last element of an array, and returns that element.
`.slice(-1)` returns you an array with last sub-string, and `.pop()` pull out the value of sub-string. @Thomas

Comment: why not just get the last value from the array that `.split('/')` returns? why do you need to `.slice(-1)` here? like `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Comment: @Robin what Thomas is saying is that you already have an array on which you can "pull out the value of sub-string" using `.pop()` before you even call `.slice(-1)`

Comment: I understand now , you don't need slice when use `split`, split itself return the array of substring. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()` is the winner.

Comment: @Thomas answer is edited, with `pop()` you don't need use `slice()`

Answer (score 2):

Try  with slice

```
window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]
```

```js
console.log("http://localhost/study/78/comparative".split('/').slice(-1)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. This one was the first. I preffer to use less methods (just `slice(-1)[0]`) than with `slice(-1).pop()`

Comment: @pmiranda or just `split('/').pop()` as I suggested...